# Async query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm in C# and using Entity Framework with a database-first approach, and I would like to do a query similar to this query but in an asynchronous way:

```
[Route("api/Tests/get/by/flight/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Test))]
public IHttpActionResult getByFlightTodayId(int id)
{
    var testList = db.Tests.SqlQuery("Select * from Tests where Tests.AircraftId=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", id)).ToList<Test>();
    return Ok(testList);
}
```

I have an example but it returns only one result - not an array.

```
[Route("api/Tests/get/by/flight/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Test))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getByFlightId(int id)
{
    Test test = await db.Tests.FirstAsync(r => r.AircraftId == id);

    if (test == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(test);
}
```

Also, I want to do an inner join query but I don't know how to do this.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have foreign key references between tables means, you can use `db.Tests.Include(x=>x.TableName)`

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, can you add an example of what result are you expecting?

Comment: Tests.aircraftId is a foreign key and I want all the tests an aircraft passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like below:

```
var test = await db.Tests.Where(r => r.AircraftId == id).ToListAsync();
```

For Inner join, there will be foreign key relationship between 2 tables. Then you can use below query:

```
var test = await db.Aircraft.Include(x=>x.Tests).ToListAsync();
```

You can apply `.Where` condition, if you want to filter records in that.

Comment: I do this but an error occured : "Cannot implicitly convert  type : 'system.Collections.Generic.List<toulouseTech2;Models.Test>' to 'toulouseTech2.Models.Test'

Comment: Try now, change Test to `var` or `List<Test>`

Comment: it's working !!! Thanks a lot. 
Can you tell me how can I do this for an inner join query like :
 Select * From Aircraft Inner Join Test On aircraft.Id = test.AircraftId